# Angular 8: Add input field in a form with a button Error Code

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I need to add an input field into my form with a button.
Here my code : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-input-field-with-a-button)
I got some error in my code.
I got this in my browser console: `Cannot find control with name: '0'` and `AuditsComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function` 
And in my angular server : `ERROR in src/app/components/audits/audits.component.ts(50,26): error TS2345: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

Thanks for contributing !

Comment: So you want an input field on top of the button? Where do you want to place it?

Comment: fixed your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-8-add-input-field-in-a-form-with-a-button what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Thx @C_Ogoo, I want to have a textarea by default. And when i click on boutton "Ajouter" a textarea will appear under the initial textarea. If you click again on the button another textarea appear under ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody helped me with my error. I corrected it in my stackblitz.

I didn't give a good property for my `arrayItems`.

**Before** *(incorrect)*:

```
arrayItems= []
```

**After** *(correct)*:

```
arrayItems: any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm correcting your code

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfrx5u
```

you must install an import in app.module.ts

1. angular material
2. import a MatInputModule
3. for reactive forms input ReactiveFormsModule

   ```
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';  

    and in NgModule

   imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatInputModule],
   ```